# Only 5GHz networks showing, 2.4GHz networks hidden

Tags: debian, wifi

I've just installed debian on my Lenovo E530 laptop and have been trying for the past couple of hours to get the 2.4GHz wireless to work. All of the wireless in my home and most of the places I go is 2.4GHz.

There seems to be very little (if any) information regarding this online.

If you required any output, please request and I will update this post.

My network controller: `03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n`

Answer (score 0):

Luckily (with very little linux knowledge) I have managed to fix this. I will post the solution for anyone else or has the same issue and is lost.

First of all you need to download the drivers from the Broadcom website [Broadcom Drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php).

Next, follow the instructions in the [README](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt) to compile and install your own copy of the drivers. **Read the whole README**. For some reason `make clean` didn't work for me, but `make` did with no troubles.

The next problem was that on reboot the drivers wouldn't work or defaulted back to the 5GHz setting. The critical part here was this:

```
Follow these steps to have the driver load as part of the boot process:

# load driver as described above
# cp wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless 
# depmod -a

# echo modeprobe wl >> /etc/rc.local  (Fedora/SUSE)

Ubuntu ships a version of wl.ko, so those need to be disabled.  On my 
system the were several versions, so I searched and renamed the .ko's
like this:

# sh: for i in `find /lib /var -name wl\.ko`; do mv $i ${i}.orig; done
```

I'm using Debian, but the last bit was still necessary. I had to copy my compile of `wl.ko` back again afterwards. Hopefully this solves the issue for anyone else. If you can't get it to work, try changing the order of the steps (or even omitting some). For some odd reason the Broadcom drivers installed via the package manager didn't work for me, but these ones I compiled myself.